# How to denote length or any other measurement

Tags: grammar

How exactly would I say that a certain object is a certain length. Would it just be

(noun)の　長さは　(number) (units)。

This question got me wondering how I would say any other sort of measurement. Can any quantifiable quality of an object be expressed by simply

(noun)の　(length/weight/frequency etc)は　(number)(units)。

This way of speaking is very close to how I would say the same thing in English (The car's length is 14 feet. etc) which has me thinking this might not be the right way to say it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Almost.  Where is the verb (or a verb-like word)?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that (noun)の「高さ・長さ」は○○○ is correct, see for example [here](http://www.fujiyama-navi.jp/quiz/column6/) or [here](http://www.fujisan-net.jp/data/article/1073.html) or [even here](http://www.nao.ac.jp/faq/a0303.html) or [this one](http://b.high.hokudai.ac.jp/~konno/soutairon/r14/). It is also useful to compare lengths of different things, or height of different people etc...

However, there is another way to express the same idea:
`(noun)は ○○○の「高さ・長さ」 [だ・です・がある」`

Which would be closer obviously to "This thing is 10 meters long" rather than "The thing's length is 10 meters".

See a few examples :

```
 富士山は３７７６メートルの高さがある。
 その塔は３１２メートルの高さだ。
```

Comment: "(noun)は「高さ・長さ」の ○○○ [だ・です・ある」"  Did you really mean to say this?  Your examples are not in that structure (and they are correct).

Comment: Oops thank you, I remodeled the pattern to add brackets and the right size of "rounds" and apparently screwed myself in the process...

Answer (score 1):

You can say...

(noun)の長さ・重さ・高さは(number)(unit)です。
eg.
ネクタイの長さは１４５センチです。
百万円の重さは１００グラムです。
あべのハルカスの高さは３００メートルです。

(noun)は長さ・重さ・高さ(が)(number)(unit)です。/が(number)(unit)あります。
eg.
ネクタイは長さ(が)１４５センチです。/長さが１４５センチあります。
百万円は重さ(が)１００グラムです。/重さが１００グラムあります。
あべのハルカスは高さ(が)３００メートルです。/高さが３００メートルあります。

(noun)は(number)(unit)の長さ・重さ・高さです。/の長さ・重さ・高さがあります。
eg.
ネクタイは１４５センチの長さです。/の長さがあります。
百万円は１００グラムの重さです。/の重さがあります。
あべのハルカスは３００メートルの高さです。/の高さがあります。